# Mysql UPDATE doesn't updates data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a weird problem when using my PHP file to update data using Mysql database.

here my code in file.php :

```
.....
.....
$con=mysqli_connect("mysite","user","mypass","mydb");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->id);
$sql = "UPDATE invites SET status='rejected' where id ='$id'";
....
....
```

I call it in my browser, like :

```
https://mysite/phpfile/file.php?id=224
```

But it doesn't updates my data. If I change the $id directly like :

```
$id = 224;
```

It changes my data.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: What you get if you call `var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));`

Comment: `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))` will expect your data in the body payload `{"id":123}` not in query string.

Comment: Use prepared statements. Have you checked for errors after executing the statment? Where do you execute your update?

Comment: I'm sorry all, that was my bad. The fault is not in my php codes, but in my application(a file that call another file to call my php file in the server) when doing payload, thank you to @AbhikChakraborty, you've helped me to find the solution, it works now. :) Thanks..

Comment: here is what I'm doing, changes usersService.updateInviteReject({dataInvite.inviteId}) to usersService.updateInviteReject({'id': dataInvite.inviteId})

Answer (score -1):

You should replace

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->id);
```

with

```
id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['id']);
```

You are reading the raw request data through the input stream then you decode it from JSON (although the stream you are reading is not in JSON format) and then you escape the id (which is not there of course.
The id you are looking for is already put by PHP in the $_REQUEST superglobal. No need for all the rest ...

Comment: It works when I calling the php file directly from my browser. Thanks for your comment, but I've discovered that the fault was not in my php codes, It was my another page that failed to call this php file in my server. I forget to send the right parameter into its.